# Visual C++ 2008 runtime components availability on a clean OS installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have developed an application which uses the MFCs of VStudio 2008 for its UI, and thus expects some VStudio 2K8 runtime libraries to be present on the system it is launched. Does anyone know on which Windows Platform the MFC runtime of VStudio 2K8 are available per default (after a clean install of the OS)?

I think there are available with a clean installation of Vista. Are they available on clean XP installation?

Comment: As much as you like them to be available, they are not.  Note that there are 3 versions of them.

Comment: What are you going to do when you have this list of OSes (assuming it is not empty as I suspect it is)? Require one of those OSes? Install the dlls if it's not one of those OSes? If the later, using the merge module should do the right thing regardless, if the former that seems sort of arbitrary. If you really don't want to deal with shipping MFC, you can statically link against it (of course then there are the servicing problems).

Comment: I guess that soon or later, I should ship the application with an installation program! :-)

Comment: Statically link, of course. Thanks. The result can be seen at www.winitor.net/en/pestudio.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **always** need to install the Visual Studio runtime redistributable to be sure it's there.

However, one option if you only need one or two of the dlls is to place the redistributable dlls next to your own .exe. This can dramatically reduce the download size, and (by just adding a couple of files along with your exe) avoids having to do anything special with merge modules etc in your installer.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I just need three of these. However when I deliver these in the directory of my application (PeStudio), this has some side effects since some of these are WinSxS libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You should [distribute the runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a5c84275-3b97-4ab7-a40d-3802b2af5fc2&displaylang=en) whatever version the target OS is. On the linked page, MS states:

> The Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)
>   installs runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries required to
>   run applications developed with Visual C++ SP1 on a computer 
>   that does not have Visual C++ 2008 SP1 installed.

So I will take the sure way and make no assumption.

Comment: Somehow it looks like Vista (and later versions) delivers these (as well as many many others) during its (clean) installation.

Comment: Does someone knows a link that documents wich (MFC) runtime libraries are installed on which OS (clean) vesions? Thanks for any hint!